# Opening apps at the left of the dock

Tags: dock

My dock is organized with more commonly used apps at the left side. I would like, that when an app (not already in the dock) is opened, it should show up on the *left* and not on the right. Is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not. You can only change the position of the dock, but not where 'undocked' apps appear.

The only solution I can think of is to move the active application to the first position. This, however, will add the application permanently to the dock.